# Using Github to notify users about important updates

Tags: email, github, notifications

I am looking for out a way to notify users via email and/or GH issues in their repo to inform them( based on our internal CI that uses their public data)  to update their repo date.  Looking for an easy and non-intrusive way to use GH email notification or another mail client to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Github + Slack integration.
https://github.com/integrations/slack

Good work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).